# InsertInOrder Function for a Linkedlist

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a function `InsertInOrder()` that inserts an item in the correct place without disturbing the order.

Ex:
`LinkedList` before [3,5,6] after inserting 4 ---> [3,4,5,6].

I have created the function but some reason it's not working as expected.

I'm testing the code on a Windows form application by entering ISBNs,

What went wrong:

First I inserted 23, then I inserted 10, expecting to be placed before 23 but here's what happened (image below):
[What went wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBxp9.png)

Please find the code below:

**LinkListGen Class**

```
class LinkListGen<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        private LinkGen<T> list;

        public LinkListGen()
        {
            list = null;
        }

        public void AddItem(T item)
        {
            list = new LinkGen<T>(item, list); //create a new link on the front of the list

        }

        public void AppendItem(T item)
        {
            LinkGen<T> temp = list;

            if (temp == null)
            {
                list = new LinkGen<T>(item);
            }
            else
            {
                while (temp.Next != null)
                {
                    temp = temp.Next;
                }
                temp.Next = new LinkGen<T>(item);
            }
        }

        public string DisplayList()
        {
            string buffer = "";
            LinkGen<T> temp = list; //temp starts beginning of list
            while (temp != null) //not at end of list
            {
                buffer = buffer + temp.Data.ToString() + ",";
                temp = temp.Next; //move along a link

            }

            return buffer;

        }

        public void RemoveItem(T item)
        {
            LinkGen<T> temp = list;
            LinkListGen<T> newList = new LinkListGen<T>();
            while (temp != null)
            {
                if (item.CompareTo(temp.Data) != 0)
                {
                    newList.AppendItem(temp.Data);
                }
                temp = temp.Next;
            }
            list = newList.list;
        }

        public void InsertInOrder (T item)
        {
            LinkGen<T> temp = list;
            LinkListGen<T> newList = new LinkListGen<T>();

            if (list == null)
            {
                AppendItem(item);
            }

            else
            {
                while (temp != null)
                {
                    if(list.Data.CompareTo(item) < 0)
                    {
                        newList.AppendItem(list.Data);
                        temp = temp.Next;
                    }

                    else if(list.Data.CompareTo(item) > 0)
                    {
                        newList.AppendItem(item);
                        newList.AppendItem(list.Data);
                        temp = temp.Next;
                    }
                    newList.AppendItem(list.Data);
                    temp = temp.Next;

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Windows Form App code**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        LinkListGen<Book> ISBNList = new LinkListGen<Book>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            double insertedISBN = Convert.ToDouble(ISBNTextBox.Text);
            Book newBook = new Book(insertedISBN);
            ISBNList.InsertInOrder(newBook);
            DisplayLabel.Text = ISBNList.DisplayList();
        }

        private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double insertedISBN = Convert.ToDouble(ISBNTextBox.Text);
            Book removeBook = new Book(insertedISBN);
            ISBNList.RemoveItem(removeBook);
            DisplayLabel.Text = ISBNList.DisplayList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the perfect time for you to learn how to use the debugger. Start again, input the first 10, let the code run, and when you are going to input 23, put a breakpoint at the beginning of `InsertInOrder` and go step by step until it finishes. It should be fairly easy to see why you end up inserting 23 twice.

Comment: there's a lot going on in the code, but just looking at the while loop you should break once you've found the place to add the new value (thats why its added twice). also, only add the value once the next one is larger (or last if there isn't a larger one), that would explain placement..

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I tried using the debugger and managed to solve the duplication by removing ```newList.AppendItem(List.Data);``` after the ending else if curly bracket, but now when I try adding a third value (less than the 2 values inserted) the Form stops responding and freezes.

Comment: It's good that you managed to find that issue! As for the freezing, that normally means that the application is still "processing", so there might be an infinite loop (which you can detect by putting a breakpoint, hitting "continue" to let it run fast and see if it ever stops breaking at that point)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes it is running into an infinite loop, but I couldn't figure out why it is not breaking, because the the 3rd number I enter is less than the other 2 so it should satisfy the first `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, that you call `AppendItem` at `InsertInOrder`, which adds element to the end of the list, instead pure pointer manipulation.
At the same time, you shouldn't recreate list at `InsertInOrder` to avoid memory/time overhead.
Try next code, not tested:

```cs
        public void InsertInOrder(T item)
        {
            var node = new LinkGen<T>(item);
            if (list == null)
            {
                list = node;
                return;
            }

            var current = list;
            while (current != null)
            {
                if (current.Data.CompareTo(item) < 0)
                {
                    // current is last element
                    if (current.Next == null)
                    {
                        current.Next = node;
                        break;
                    }
                    
                    // current.Next.Data is equal or greater than new value
                    // so set new node.Next to current.Next and current.Next to new node
                    if (current.Next.Data.CompareTo(item) >= 0)
                    {
                        node.Next = current.Next;
                        current.Next = node;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                current = current.Next;
            }
        }
```